# Uploading photos to facebook, Facebook App or Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook

I am working on a website that allows people to upload photos to their facebook account (as if the user manually uploaded those photos to facebook), and the uploaded photos will be hosted on facebook instead of my server. Should I develop a facebook application or use facebook connect?

Answer (score 0):

When you use facebook connect, you actually create a facebook application that will make it possible to "communicate" with facebook from your website.

You should know that a facebook application runs in facebook while facebook connect gives you the possibility to link whatever you have in your website to Facebook.

Though, I'm not sure if what you want to do is doable using the Facebook connect API.